# How to make to set redirect uri in OIDC on apache proxy when session expired obtaining status code 401

Tags: apache, session, proxy, openid-connect

I searched on the internet but I did not find the response.
My app infrastructure is the followed:
In the same machine there are application back-end, front end (Play framework 2.2.3) and Apache proxy 2.4.
Application back-end has the 9001 port in listened.
I configured virtual host on apache proxy, that all requests on the 8080 port must be redirect on authentication page and the user must insert sso and password.

I configured OPEN ID connect (OIDC) with Virtual host on apache proxy listened on a defined port (port 8080).
My configuration into httpd.conf is the followed:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

<VirtualHost *:8080>

    ServerAdmin app@localhost
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:9001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9001/
    #DocumentRoot /Apache24/var/www/html

    #this is required by mod_auth_openidc
    OIDCCryptoPassphrase a-random-secret-used-by-apache-oidc-and-balancer

    ###OIDCProviderMetadataURL ${KC_ADDR}/auth/realms/${KC_REALM}/.well-known/openid-configuration
                OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://host+domain/fss/.well-known/openid-configuration
    ###OIDCClientID ${CLIENT_ID}
                OIDCClientID app-PROD
    ###OIDCClientSecret ${CLIENT_SECRET}
                OIDCClientSecret secretTest
    #OIDCRedirectURI http://${HOSTIP}/${CLIENT_APP_NAME}/redirect_uri
    OIDCRedirectURI http://serverApp.domain:8080/app-inspector/redirect_uri
    OIDCSessionInactivityTimeout 3600
    OIDCSessionMaxDuration 3600
    # maps the prefered_username claim to the REMOTE_USER environment variable
    ###OIDCRemoteUserClaim preferred_username
    OIDCRemoteUserClaim sub
    ###<Location /${CLIENT_APP_NAME}/>
    <Location />
        AuthType openid-connect
        Require valid-user
    </Location>    
</VirtualHost>
```

While I'm navigating on the app front-end when the session expired I receive, front-end side, status code 401 Unauthorized.

[image]

I don't understood the configuration, apache proxy side, with OIDC when session expired (401 status code) to redirect the user to login page.
Must I configure just the property side apache proxy into virtual host ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your backend creates a session as well and it is that session that expires? If so make sure that your backend session lasts longer than the proxy session.